# Updating contents of input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a script in js to add multiple fields in HTML page. Each field is accompanied by a '+' and '-' button to update the value of input field. However, the number of input field and corresponding button is defined at the runtime. Eg, if I enter 3, then there will be 3 sets of input field and 3 sets of '+' and '-' buttons. How can I use the id of the input field dynamically to update the contents, that is, the first '+' button will update the contents of first input field only?

Comment: Share what you have so far

Comment: By passing differing arguments to your onclick listener.

Comment: I saw a similar thing carried out by e-commerce websites. The 'view your cart' option have one input fields for each product. If I add more products to cart, more input fields will appear. How is it carried out? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can split the id to 2 strings like this:

```
var count = 1;
var idField;
var idPlus;
var idRed;

function add(){
   idField = ["field",count].join();
   idPlus = ["btnPlus",count].join();
   idRed = ["btnRed",count].join();
   count++;
}
```

and now you have different ids for different sets of elements

Comment: I saw a similar thing carried out by e-commerce websites. The 'view your cart' option have one input fields for each product. If I add more products to cart, more input fields will appear. How is it carried out? Any idea?

Comment: I believe they already have those field hidden in advance and they "create them" (they actually only making them not hidden...), whenever there is a need to.... Buy my way of actually creating these elements special id's is viable as well. But it is only to create special id's for every new element, if you want to create a new element use DOM HTML or JQuery.